# Delete event doesn't get hit

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a control class that inherit from a base class. The control class majorly has a overwritten image control with upload and delete button. I have an event to delete the image if the delete button is clicked. However, the ibDelete_Click event is never hit.

```
public class ImageUpload : UserControlBase
{
   ibDelete.Click += ibDeleteFile_Click;

   private void ibDelete_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
   {
    . . .
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide snippets of the aspx markup and codebehind that assigns the class to the expected button?

Comment: That snippet would not be able to compile, but the question implies that the application runs. The line where the method is being attached to the Click event must be within something else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the `ibDelete.Click += ...` on the instance of the object, not in the class itself.
And the UserControl will only expose the Event.

For example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new ImageUpload();
        x.Click += ibDeleteFile_Click;
    }

    private void ibDelete_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //...
    }
```

Comment: public class ImageUpload : UserControlBase
{                                                                                                               
   ImageButton ibDelete = new ImageButton { ID = ("ibDelete_ImageFile") };
   ibDelete.Click += ibDeleteFile_Click;

   private void ibDelete_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
   {
    . . .
   }
}                                                                                                                          
     Sorry, I left the line out.